Question about covering space of punctured unit disk
Let $\mathbb{H}$ be the upper half-plane and $a \in \mathbb{R}^*,\, p:\mathbb{H} \to \mathbb{D} \setminus \{0\}, \, p(z) = e^\frac{2 \pi i z}{|a|}$. I want to show that $p$ is a covering map.

 What I've tried:

First, clear $p$ is continuous and surjective. I think I need to start with an $y \in \mathbb{D} \setminus \{0\}$ and take an open disk $D \subset \mathbb{D} \setminus \{0\}$ to be a neighbourhood of $y$. Now, because disk is open and connected, there exists a holomorphic branch of logarithm in $D$. It's ok this start? How I can continue? Thanks!

This is a fine start. You need to ultimately show that given a point $x \in \mathbb{D} \setminus 0$, there is a sufficiently small neighborhood $U \ni x$ such that $p^{-1}(U)$ consists of a disjoint union of homeomorphic copies of $U$ (with $p$ giving the homeomorphism). In this case, you should show that these copies are given by the images of $U$ under the of the various branches of the logarithm.

@CJDowd ummm.. ok. But how can I show this?

@PaulFrost $\mathbb{H} = {z \in \mathbb{C} : \operatorname{Im}(z) > 0}$ is the upper half-plane

@MathLearner You should include this in your question.

@PaulFrost done

You should first solve the same question for the map of the real line to the circle.

Write $\mathbb H = \mathbb R \times (0,\infty)$ and define $h : \mathbb D \setminus \{0 \} \to S^1 \times (0,1), h(z) = (\frac{z}{\lvert z \rvert}, \lvert z \rvert)$. The map $h$ is a homeomorphism. Showing that $p$ is a covering is therefore equivalent to showing that $h \circ p$ is a covering. With $b = 2\pi/ \lvert a \rvert$ we have
$$(h \circ p)(x,y) = (e^{b i x}, e^{-by}) .$$
Thus $h \circ p = f \times g$ with $f(x) = e^{bix}$ and $g(y) = e^{-by}$. Clearly $g : (0,\infty) \to (0,1)$ is a homeomorphisms, in particular a covering. Hence it suffices to show that $f : \mathbb R \to S^1$ is a covering (because the Cartesian product of coverings is a covering).
That $f$ is a covering is obvious. It is well-known that $F : \mathbb R \to S^1, F(x) = e^{2\pi ix}$, is a covering. Since $\phi :  \mathbb R \to \mathbb R, \phi(x) = \frac{b}{2\pi}x$, is a homeomorphism, we see that $F \circ \phi$ is a covering. But $(F \circ \phi)(x) = e^{ibx} = f(x)$.
